# Reactive value rendering

Tags: r, shiny

I am struck with small issue here. When the application runs, by default, it should show 101 and then by the user selectinput, the value should changes. Below is the repo

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h3("Material switch examples"),
  
  selectInput("sel", "select number", choices = c("",1:100),selected = ""),
  dataTableOutput("df"),
  textOutput("df1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  num <- reactiveVal(c(101))
  
  observeEvent(input$sel, {
    num <- input$sel
  })
  
  
  # output$df <- DT::renderDataTable({
  #   datatable(data,caption = "Iris",options = list(dom = 'ft'),escape=FALSE, selection = list(mode = 'single',target = 'cell'))
  # })
  
  output$df1 <- renderText({
    as.numeric(num())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Seems like you have `selected = ""` in `selectInput(...)`

Comment: Yeah I know. The values should be from 1 to 100. But by default it should by 101 (when the app opens)

Answer (score 0):

The second occurence of `num` overwrites the first one (as in ordinary R code):

```
  num <- reactiveVal(c(101))
  num <- reactive({
    input$sel
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h3("Material switch examples"),
  
  selectInput("sel", "select number", choices = c("",1:100), selected = NULL),
  dataTableOutput("df"),
  textOutput("df1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  num <- reactiveVal(101)
  
  observeEvent(input$sel, {
    num(req(input$sel))
  })

  output$df1 <- renderText({
    as.numeric(num())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```